# break lines in node causes odd actions

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following exmaple, I want to color some text in node. The typeset showes that `\color` only act to the first linebreak. Why is it not able to work till the second linebreak, and how to do that?

PS: I wonder if there is a better way to make the latter `rotate=` overwrite the formers. I don't find related description in the manuel.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz\node[rotate=30,fill=yellow!80!black,align=left,rotate=60]
{\color{red}This is a\\ demonstration text for\\\color{blue} alignments.};
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Clarification question: what do you mean by overwriting `rotate=`? Why do you have two `rotate` options, instead of just one with the required rotation?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the output so that the offending behavior is clear.

Comment: @Marijn The first rotate setup a default value, and the second is used for costom modification.

Comment: Why do you need a default value, why not set _only_ the custom value? Is the code automatically generated?

Comment: @Marijn In my concrete project, the text of node is with 90 degree by default(with many other options), and there are cases the text need to be 0 degree.

Comment: Ok, but if a node needs to be 0 degrees, why don't you just delete `rotate=90` for that node?

Comment: The default value rotate=90 is for most cases and has been built into my code. When there are cases for rotate=0, I want to append it  to overwrite rotate=90 with rotate=0 just like most tikz options do. But it seems that the value of rotate is added, not overwrite the former value. I don't find any explaination and solution for this in manuel.

Comment: Using align is equivalent to putting a one column tabular into the node.  BTW, using textwidth is equivalent to putting a \parbox into the node.

Answer (score 1):

Use a minipage environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz\node[rotate=30,fill=yellow!80!black,align=left,rotate=60,align=center]
{\begin{minipage}{1.5in}
\color{red}\noindent This is a\\demonstration text for\\\color{blue} alignments.
\end{minipage}};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, `minipage` is a solution. But I find that it can't centerline the content as the following example showes`\tikz\node[rotate=30,fill=yellow!80!black,align=left,rotate=-30,align=center,minimum width=0.5in]{\begin{minipage}{0in}\color{red}\noindent M\\W\\\color{blue}O\end{minipage}};`